# Alert on value change in select

Tags: jquery, html-select

I'm trying to alert the user when the value of a select changes to a specific one, but I have multiple select in my page (one for each user).

Here is what I tried: http://jsfiddle.net/mEFQq/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").change(function(){
        if($(this).text() == "Chef")
            {
                alert();
            }
        });
});
```

My wish is to have an alert when the select changes to the value "Chef".

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

something like this perhaps: http://jsfiddle.net/mEFQq/1/

You need to use the .val() function, not the .text() function when working with selects.

Also you need to compare with the value attribute (1 in this case) not the actual text value.

The code looks like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == "1")
            {
                alert('value 1 (wich refers to Chef) got selected');
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that using the `.text()` method will return all the text on your `select` elements, not just the "selected" one, and if you tried to use `.val()`, you'd the selected element's `value` attribute instead (if they had no set `value`, you could use `.val()`).

I suggest you change your `if` to: `if($(this).children(':selected').text() == "Chef")`, like this:

```
$("select").change(function(){
    if($(this).children(':selected').text() == "Chef")
        {
    alert();
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/YCznv/

Answer (score 0):

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mEFQq/3/)

You can do something like this:

```
if($(this).find('option:selected').text() == "Chef")
```